# Remove customers from a list if first name duplicated and last name is null

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to remove duplicates from a list of objects based on `first name` which `last name` is null
Can we do it in java 8?

```
 public void test() {
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    Customer customer1 = new Customer();
    customer1.setFirstName("Abc");
    customer1.setLastName("def");

    Customer customer2 = new Customer();
    customer2.setFirstName("Abc");
    customer2.setLastName(null);

    Customer customer3 = new Customer();
    customer3.setFirstName("toms");
    customer3.setLastName(null);

    customers.add(customer1);
    customers.add(customer2);
    customers.add(customer3);

    customers =  customers.stream().filter(c -> {
        return c.getLastName() != null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(customers);

}
```

this is my Customer.class

```
private class Customer {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

  //get set


}
```

I don't want to remove `customer3` because its even `lastName` is null but not duplicate

`customers` keeps `customer1` and `customer3`
remove `customer2` because `firstName` duplicated with `customer1` and `lastName` is null

Comment: Yes, we can. Use an `Iterator` to loop over the list, and call it's `remove()` method. Where is the problem? Try to ask a precise question. Besides you didn't even bother to post a piece of code that even compiles.

Comment: updated my post thank you

Comment: You still didn't manage to provide a compileable version.  Is it asked too much?`customer.setFirstName("Abc");`

Comment: updated my question thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in two steps by first collecting all customers that have full names (and thus might have duplicates) into a list of first names and then removing any customers from the original list that have a null surname and exist in my collected list

```
List<String> properNames = customers.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getLastName() != null)
        .map(Customer::getFirstName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

customers.removeIf(c -> c.getLastName() == null
        && properNames.contains(c.getFirstName()));
```

Comment: Performance can be improved by using a `HashSet` for `properNames` instead of a `List` because it won't have to iterate over all elements for `contains()`.